# Probability: basic question and concept

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have always been struggling with the problem, in particular, I usually have great difficulty in differenting when should I  multiply n! to take care of the ordering, and when should I not do so. For simple question, this might not be an issue; but if this basic concept is not understood throughly, this will extend to more complicate question. Because of this, I hope you guys can correct my understanding of basic probably.

For instance, a very basic question:

12 balls in a pool, 7 green, 2 yellow, 3 orange.  What is the probability that of drawing 2 yellow and 2 orange?

My attempt:

First Approach:

the simplest way is to use view each draw is independent (this approach I have no problem):
$$  \frac{3}{12}\cdot\frac{2}{11}\cdot\frac{2}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{9}\cdot4! $$
4! because such "independent draw" could happen 4! times. So this approach I have no problem.

---

Second Approach:
\begin{align*}
P(\text{2 yellow AND 2 orange})&=\frac{\text{# of ways you can draw 2 yellow AND 2 orange}}{\text{# of ways draw 4 balls}}   \\
&=\frac{\binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{2}}{\binom{12}{4}}
\end{align*}

my understanding:

- $\binom{3}{2}$ is the number of ways you can form 2 orange out of the 3, where the ordering is not important.
- you mutiply by $\binom{2}{2}$ is because for each of $\binom{3}{2}$ ways, you can have $\binom{2}{2}$ ways to combine them with the yellow balls.

**It terms out that I am missing a factor of 4.**  It turns out that I am having true difficulty with this type of problem. What can I do to improve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you count the number of ways of drawing the balls such that balls of the same color are distinguishable and such that order does not matter, then you should have
$$\frac{\binom{3}{2} \cdot 1}{\binom{12}{4}},$$
as you have written.

The first approach is incorrect. $\frac{3}{12} \cdot \frac{2}{11} \cdot \frac{2}{10} \cdot \frac{1}{9}$ is the probability of choosing orange first, orange second, yellow third, and yellow fourth, as well as any other ordering. You only want to multiply this by $\frac{4}{2!2!}$ (the number of ways of arranging "orange, orange, yellow, yellow" in a row) instead of $4!$ (number of permutations of 4 distinguishable objects). The erroneous factor of $4$ comes because each arrangement of "orange, orange, yellow, yellow" is counted 4 times instead of once because you distinguished between the two oranges and the two yellows when multiplying by $4!$.

Comment: yes, thank you very much, can I ask you further question? First of all, I agree with your answer. In short, you are saying that OYOY and OOYY is distinct and you dont differentiate O1 and O2 or Y1 and Y2 and Y3, etc

Comment: Second, I am having question on (3C2) term. (3C2) means the number of ways you can form a group of 2 from 3 distinct objects. So that, you are treating each Orange balls (O1, O2, O3) as distinct objects, and you are seaking the number of groups of 2 you can form from 3 distincts Orange balls. (eg, O1O2, O1O3, O2O3). So here is my confusion: in my first comment, where you don't differentiate objects of same color, but now, you are differentiate them in (3C2) term. And I know this must be a misunderstanding from me. Can you please explain? I think the answer to this question is my key concern

Comment: @kuku As I wrote above, the approach with the $\binom{3}{2}$ involves the balls of the same color being *distinguishable*. This is ok as long as you assume the same thing when computing the denominator.